# how can i combine 2 sheets with lists based on a single value?

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets with info. I need a master sheet that lists the entire row if it is false. it needs to be an array in case it is changed to true, it will be removed from the master list. is this possible without VB?

SHEET1

```
animal  name    T/F
mouse   minnie  TRUE
dog     jeff    FALSE
cat     jerry   TRUE
pig     steve   FALSE
```

SHEET2

```
animal  name    T/F
mouse   Micky   TRUE
dog     paul    FALSE
```

MASTER

```
dog     jeff    FALSE
pig     steve   FALSE
dog     paul    FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Power Query for that. Power query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get & Transform.

- Create a connection-only query to the table on Sheet1
- create a connection-only query to the table on Sheet2
- append the two queries and set a filter to show False values only
- return the result to the Master sheet.

All this can be done by clicking ribbon commands. No VBA required. When the data in sheets 1 or 2 changes, just click Refresh All on the Data ribbon.

Comment: yes! it works beautifully! is there an easy way to save as and send to a friend in a way that they don't have to re-create the queries?

Comment: If you send them the workbook with the query, they will need the same version of Power Query and access to the source files if they want to refresh the query. If you just want to share the technique, you can click Advanced Editor in the Query Editor window and copy the M code. This will include the path to the data source, which your friend will need to adjust to a source they can access.